# conversion to byte gives this error : Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, string, char, type-conversion, byte

i am using `convert.tobyte` to convert string to byte. the problem is if the data is:

`string data = "5";`

`byte b = Convert.tobyte(data);` works fine.

but, if

`string data = "S"`

`byte b = Convert.tobyte(data);` DOESN'T WORK!

`ERROR : Input string was not in a correct format`

What is wrong and how to solve it?

Note: i am extracting a values from `textbox`, so the conversion works only if the input is number digits, not characters.

how to include the characters?

Thanks.

Comment: `tobye` shouldn't be `ToByte`? And `Convert` not `convert` IMO.

Comment: The code even cannot be compiled

Comment: @SonerGönül, it is typing error, i didn't copy. anyways i edited.

Comment: If my answer is not satisfying, then tell us what you are trying to achieve? What should be the result of converting "S" to byte? It's ASCII code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly how `Convert.ToByte` method works http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y57wwkzk.aspx

Only digits in string accepted.

Did you meant converting the string to byte array? If so, use:

```
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourString);
```

For strings containing only ASCII characters, the size of array will be equal to length of your string and every byte in array will be an `ord` value for the character. If string contains multibyte characters the size of array will be greater than length of string.

Comment: your answer works, i am trying to avoid the array. is there a way to this without the array?

Answer (score 2):

When you are not sure if a variable of string type could be correctly converted to a number you need to use the TryParse family of methods like [Byte.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.tryparse.aspx) method

```
string data = "S";
byte b;
if(byte.TryParse(data, out b))
   Console.Writeline("Worked: " + b.ToString());
```

The TryParse has the advantage to not throw an exception if the string cannot be converted to a number and return just false or true while the out parameter is filled with the converted value if possible.

Comment: yes it doesn't throw exception, but it doesn't work either. it is just blank

Comment: Well if you need a number the letter 'S' cannot be converted to a number and this is the answer instead if you need to convert the Ascii value of the letter S to its corresponding numeric value then you need the answer from @elmovankielmo